# Pythonのクラスのメソッドを辞書にまとめたい

Tags: python

```
class test:
    def method1(self):
        print('1')

    def method2(self):
        print('2')
```

というコードを、

```
class test:
    methods = {}

    def method1(self):
        print('1')
    
    methods['m1'] = self.method1

    def method2(self):
        print('2')

    methods['m2'] = self.method2
```

として、`x = test()`に対して、`x.method1()`の代わりに`x.methods['m1']()`のようにkeyを指定してメソッドを実行できるようにしたいのですが、エラーが出てしまいます。（`NameError: name 'self' is not defined`）

どのように変更すればよいでしょうか？

Comment: もしかすると、こちらのご質問は [XY 問題](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2701/19110) に陥っているかもしれません。なぜこのようなことがしたくなったのかの情報が質問文にあると、より適切な回答を付けられるかもしれないです。

Answer (score 0):

それを行って意味があるのか？とか、何か使い方に思わぬ制限がありそうな気がしますが、こんなパターンでの設定が考えられます。
まだやり方はありそうですが、まずは一例として。

---

- `__init__`メソッドで設定する

```
class test:
    methods = {}
    
    def method1(self):
        print('1')
    
    def method2(self):
        print('2')
    
    def __init__(self):
        test.methods['m1'] = self.method1
        test.methods['m2'] = self.method2

x = test()
x.methods['m1']()
x.methods['m2']()
```

---

- `__init__`メソッドで設定する、かつ`methods`もインスタンス変数とする

```
class test:
    
    def method1(self):
        print('1')
    
    def method2(self):
        print('2')
    
    def __init__(self):
        self.methods = {}
        self.methods['m1'] = self.method1
        self.methods['m2'] = self.method2

x = test()
x.methods['m1']()
x.methods['m2']()
```

---

- `self`は一切使わない

```
class test:
    methods = {}
    
    def method1():
        print('1')
    
    methods['m1'] = method1
    
    def method2():
        print('2')
    
    methods['m2'] = method2

x = test()
x.methods['m1']()
x.methods['m2']()
```

---

- 設定時には`self.`を使わない(=呼び出し時にインスタンスをselfとしてパラメータ指定する)

```
class test:
    methods = {}
    
    def method1(self):
        print('1')
    
    methods['m1'] = method1
    
    def method2(self):
        print('2')
    
    methods['m2'] = method2

x = test()
x.methods['m1'](x)
x.methods['m2'](x)
```

Answer (score 0):

以下はプロパティを使う方法です。

```py
class test:
  @property
  def methods(self):
    if not hasattr(self, '__methods__'):
      prefix = 'method'
      self.__methods__ = {
        m[0]+m[len(prefix):]: getattr(self, m) for m in dir(self)
        # Python 3.9 has str.removeprefix method
        # m[0]+m.removeprefix(prefix): getattr(self, m) for m in dir(self)
        if not isinstance(getattr(type(self), m), property)
           and m.startswith(prefix)
      }
    return self.__methods__

  def method1(self):
    print('1')
    
  def method2(self):
    print('2')

if __name__ == '__main__':
  x = test()
  x.methods['m1']()
  x.methods['m2']()

=>
1
2
```

Answer (score 0):

エラーが出ているのは、`self.method1` などと書かれている位置では `self` が定義されていないからです。

Python の色々な[組み込み関数](https://docs.python.org/ja/3.9/library/functions.html)たちを使うと、クラスに定義されたメソッドたちを自動的に一覧することができます。

```
class Test:
    def method_dict(self):
        self_class = type(self)
        name_and_funcs = map(lambda name: (name, getattr(self_class, name)), dir(self_class))
        return dict(filter(lambda nf: callable(nf[1]) and not nf[0].startswith("__"), name_and_funcs))
        
    def method1(self):
        print('1')

    def method2(self):
        print('2')

print(Test().method_dict())
# ==> {'method1': <function Test.method1 at 0x7f7fd8989310>, 'method2': <function Test.method2 at 0x7f7fd89893a0>, 'method_dict': <function Test.method_dict at 0x7f7fd8989280>}
```

やりたいこと次第ですが、あとはキー名の生成規則を作れば質問者さんのやりたいことができるかもしれません。

Comment: あと他にこれとか`dict(inspect.getmembers(obj, inspect.ismethod))`